# How to enable multiple clients to communicate with the server?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp, network-programming

The problem am having is that am not sure how to enable multiple clients to communicate with the server through threading, i've attempted it but I think am doing something wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ChatServer {
    ArrayList clientOutputStreams;

    public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
        BufferedReader reader;
        Socket sock;

        public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket) {
            try {
                sock = clientSocket;
                InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(
                        sock.getInputStream());
                reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
            } catch (Exception x) {

            }
        }

        public void run() {
            String message;
            try {
                while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("read" + message);
                    tellEveryone(message);
                }
            } catch (Exception x) {

            }
        }
    }

    public void go() {
        clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList();
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(5000);

            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSock.accept();
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(
                        clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                clientOutputStreams.add(writer);

                Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
                t.start();
                System.out.println("got a connection");
            }
        } catch (Exception x) {

        }
    }

    public void tellEveryone(String message) {
        Iterator it = clientOutputStreams.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            try {
                PrintWriter writer = (PrintWriter) it.next();
                writer.println(message);
                writer.flush();
            } catch (Exception x) {

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChatServer().go();
    }`enter code here`

}
```

Comment: Neither your Swing code nor indeed your entire client is relevant to a question about a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow multiple client to connect to your server you need a server to be continually looking for a new client to connect to. This can be done like:

```
while(true) {
    Socket socket = Ssocket.accept();
    [YourSocketClass] connection = new [YourSocketClass](socket);
    Thread thread = new Thread(connection);
    thread.start();
}
```

This is probably also best done in a separate server java file that can run independent of the client.